# how to make a Comprehensions for with if Python

Tags: python

I have a `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>` from my `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>` and I want to make a list of that in Comprehensions way this is my old way to do that

```
ls_parent_name_3 = []
for k in df.parent_name_3:
    if k not in ls_parent_name_3:
        ls_parent_name_3.append(k)
```

I want to do something like this

```
ls_parent_name_3 = [df.parent_name_3 for sentence in collection if not sentence in ls_parent_name_3]
```

Comment: ```from collections import OrderedDict```,```ls_parent_name_3=[k for k in df.parent_name_3 ]```, ```ls_parent_name_3=list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(ls_parent_name_3))```?

Comment: @Sujay This will raise NameError: name 'ls_parent_name_3' is not defined.

Comment: @Sujay this won't work, `ls_parent_name_3` will contain values only after the list comprehension is done, `if k not in ls_parent_name_3` is not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use a set:

```py
ls_parent_name3 = list(set(df.parent_name_3))
```